# Зачем столько пользователей в phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Объясните, пожалуйста, за что отвечает каждый пользователь, который по умолчанию есть в phpMyAdmin?

Это слепок прямо после установки XAMPP:

```
User name | Host name | Password | Global privileges | User group | Grant
Any       | %         | No       | USAGE             |            | No
Any       | localhost | No       | USAGE             |            | No
pma       | localhost | No       | USAGE             |            | No
root      | 127.0.0.1 | No       | ALL PRIVILEGES    |            | Yes
root      | ::1       | No       | ALL PRIVILEGES    |            | Yes
root      | localhost | No       | ALL PRIVILEGES    |            | Yes
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Собственно это даже не пользователи phpMyAdmin - это список MySQL-пользователей.
Первый пользователь Any - это анонимный пользователь, т.е. пользователь с логином пустая строка. Он представлен в двух вариантах - сетевой и локальный.

- `''@'%'` - сетевой доступ, с любого хоста можно обратиться к вашему
  серверу используя анонимный аккаунт.
- `''@'localhost'` - доступ с
  локальной машины. Например, вы можете удалить аккаунт ''@'%' и у вас
  остается доступ для анонимного пользователя с локальной машины.
- `pma@localhost` - пользователь из под которого работает phpMyAdmin
- `root@127.0.0.1`, `root@::1`,`root@localhost` - учетная запись суперпользователя с доступом с локальной машины (соответственно, локальный IP-адрес в IPv4, IPv6 и псевдоним localhost). Если у вас в etc/hosts прописан алиас localhost (в 99.9% случаев прописан) вам достаточно одной учетной записи.

Анонимного пользователя лучше сразу удалить, особенно, сетевого, да и локальный ни к чему. Остальных лучше оставить без изменений.